# Exception setting "TreatControlCAsInput": "The handle is invalid. in Windows PowerShell ISE

Tags: powershell, console, azure-pipelines, powershell-ise

We have a  PowerShell script that contains "[Console]::TreatControlCAsInput = $true". The script is executed in a Azure DevOps Pipeline and fails with

```
Exception setting "TreatControlCAsInput": "The handle is invalid.
"
At line:1 char:3
+   [Console]::TreatControlCAsInput = $true
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
```

We've narrowed down the issue by reproducing this with a single line of code outside of an Azure Pipeline. Simply open Windows PowerShell ISE and run this:

`[Console]::TreatControlCAsInput = $true`

If we do this in a Windows PowerShell command window, the line of code succeeds.

Does anyone know what is different about the two environments that causes this difference in behavior? We are hoping that the answer would help us understand and resolve the larger issue with the script that runs in an Azure Pipeline.

The script runs fine if executed:

1. In Cmd.exe window using Powershell.exe -File ....
2. In Windows PowerShell window

The script fails if executed in WIndows PowerShell ISE

Comment: The explanation is pretty simple: they aren't console applications. Who are you expecting to press Ctrl+C in an Azure pipeline? :)

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen. I am not expecting anyone to press Ctrl+C. But we want to take advantage of pipelines and run automatic tests of the PS code and the code contains such constructs.  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note:

- This answer focuses on the behavior of the *ISE*.
- *Azure DevOps pipelines* apparently exhibit similar behavior with respect to non-support of *interactive* console features, but - as [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) points out - such features are pointless in an environment where only *unattended* execution ever takes place, i.e. where *user interaction* is fundamentally unsupported.
- The **upshot** is:

  - Avoid the ISE if you need a full, interactive console experience, and consider migrating to Visual Studio Code (see bottom section).
  - Scripts run in Azure DevOps pipeline *must avoid use of interactive features* altogether.

---

The **Windows PowerShell ISE** does *not* allocate a [console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/consoles) *by default*, which causes attempts to call the members of the static .NET [`[Console]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Console) class to throw the exception you saw.

While it allocates a (hidden) console (used behind the scenes) *on demand* - namely the first time you run an external console application (e.g. `cmd /c ver`) - after which `[Console]` members then *can* be accessed, **any *interactive* console functionality is fundamentally unsupported in the ISE**.

Since `[Console]::TreatControlCAsInput = $true` is only relevant to *interactive* functionality, notably `[Console]::ReadKey()`:

- There is no point in setting it in the ISE, and you can simply *ignore* the failure:

  ```
   try { [Console]::TreatControlCAsInput = $true } catch {}
  ```
- However, if your script *relies* on the ability to interpret <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> as a keypress rather than a request to abort execution, you may need to find an ISE-compatible solution.

  - Note that [`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host) and `$host.UI.ReadLine()` do *not* allow configuring the behavior of <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> (they always abort), and that `$host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey()`, which does, is *not implemented* in the ISE.

---

**Note**:

- The **PowerShell ISE is [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support)** and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), including the lack of a proper console, and, more fundamentally, the inability to run [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md).
- The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

Comment: To close the loop on this post: for our needs, we ended up solving this by creating an additional bool parameter in our script and we set it to true when we invoke it  in our Pipeline. And we bypass all those console invokations when it is set to true.

if ($NoConsole -eq $false)
{
 [Console]::TreatControlCAsInput = $true 
}